# Projective linear group - solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

Let $q\geq 5$ and let PGL(2,q) be the projective general linear group.

**Question**

Do there exists a $q$ such that PGL(2,q) is solvable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$PSL(2,q)$ for all $q>3$ is simple and non-abelian, hence can not be solvable (since $G'=[G,G]$ is a normal subgroup). Since $PSL(2,q)\leq PGL(2,q)$, $PGL(2,q)$ can not be solvable either.